# How can I pass a message from outside URL to my Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message

I know there's a way for extensions and pages to communicate locally, but I need to send a message from an outside URL, have my Chrome Extension listen for it.

I have tried easyXDM in the background page, but it seems to stop listening after awhile, as if Google "turns off" the Javascript in the background page after awhile.

Comment: Could you please explain in more details how exactly it should communicate? When a user navigates to this external URL it should send some message to the extension? Or even without navigating?

Comment: Google is not turning off js in the background page that is for sure. I'd say you need to try your extension on another computer to try to find out what is happening to communication.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try some walk around and build a site with some specific data structure, and then implement a content script which will look for this specific that specific data structure, and when i finds one it can fetch the data you want to be passed to your extension.

Comment: Sorry, no polling.  I'm looking for a more efficient method such as Comet

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a content script that communicates with the page using DOM Events.. Instructions on how to do that are here:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication